# Is there a new method to call enums on Rails 5.2?

Tags: enums, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I built an app with enums and all works perfectly.
However, on a different app where I have nested forms I'm having a small problem.
Even though everything seems to work fine in the backend, on my view does not shows the result and says that I have an undefined method

Do anyone has the same problem or is just me??

**My Schema:**

```
create_table "estimate_variants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "unit", default: 0
    t.bigint "estimate_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["estimate_id"], name: "index_estimate_variants_on_estimate_id"
end
```

**My main model**

```
class Estimate < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :estimate_variants
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :estimate_variants
end
```

**My nested model**

```
class EstimateVariant < ApplicationRecord
    enum unit: { SF: 0, LF: 1 }
    belongs_to :estimate
end
```

**My view**

```
<%= form.fields_for :estimate_variants do |builder| %>
<div class="field col s12">
    <%= builder.label :unit, 'Unit' %>
    <%= form.select(unit: EstimateVariant.units.keys) %>
</div>
```

And the error I get is this:
[image]

Can someone please guide me a bit into this so I can fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I think the problem is the `select` helper in your view, try with:

```
 <%= builder.select(:unit, EstimateVariant.units.keys) %>
```

I made an example to test and work for me, and the enums in the models also work defining only the keys, and the values increase in an ascending way.

You can define:

```
enum unit: { sf: 0, lf: 1 }

or

enum unit: [:sf, lf]
enum unit: %i[sf lf]
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is with the select as well
And I tried your suggestion but it does not work for me, still getting error:

undefined method `{:unit=>["sf", "lf"]}' for #<Estimate:0x000000000f107390>

I am not sure if this has something to do with the controller but I have "unit" declared on my controller's permitted params.
I feel dumb... jeje

Comment: This part of code are inside of nested form no? Maybe is:
`<%= builder.select(:unit, EstimateVariant.units.keys) %>`

Comment: Yes, thanks!!
**You were definitely right when said _the problem was on the select_**

It happens that I made a stupid mistake over there...
Problem was that I previously configurated my styles to use selet2 for al my select-options and thus whenever I call a select-option "I have to initialize select2's script" or else the code simply wont work

Oh lord!
I feel like I fell into my own trap HAHAHA